# add description to a new polygon and save -> postgres + geoserver + openlayers -> wfs-t insert

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, postgresql, wfs-t

actually it is possible to draw a new polygon with openlayers and save it over WFS-T-insert (geoserver wfs-t 1.1.0) in my postgres-db:

```
var save = new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
title: "Save Changes",
trigger: function() {
    if(edit.feature) {
    edit.selectControl.unselectAll();
    }

var win = new Ext.Window({
    title: 'Beschreibung des Fehlerreports',
    html:'<br>',
    html:'Bitte beschreiben Sie den aufgezeigten Fehler in der Darstellung:',

    layout:'fit',
    width:500,
    height: 300,
    modal: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    shadow: false,
    closable: true,
    buttons: [
    {
        scope: this,
        text: 'Speichern',
        handler: function() { win.hide(); saveStrategy.save(); }
    },{
        scope: this,
        text: 'Abbrechen',
        handler: function() { win.hide(); }
    }]
});
win.show();    
//alert('saved');
},
displayClass: "olControlSaveFeatures"
});
```

In the saveing-window i need 3 forms to store some information (character) together with the polygon in the DB. This is the structure of the DB and the the published layer from geoserver:

DB - Postgres:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19066498/db.jpg

Geoserver - public Layer:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19066498/geoserver.jpg

Any idea what is a possible way to store these informations together with the wfs-t insert post??